# Is there a regex to the String.replaceAll method that only keeps letters and white spaces

Tags: java, replace, replaceall

I have made a program that counts the frequency of a word in a very long string. My problem is that the program is counting for example "*it" (consider * a quotation mark) and "it" as different words and therefore putting them in different categories.

I tried to replace all the punctuation marks I know of with the following code:

```
text = text.replace("\n", " ");
text = text.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ");
text = text.replace("\"", "");
text = text.replace("–", "");
text = text.replace("\t", "");
```

Unfortunately, the code didn't work and I think it is because there is a lot of different quotation marks in Unicode that I can't see a difference between, so is there a way to remove all Unicode characters except letters and whitespaces with the String.replaceAll method or do I have to make a CharArray and continue from there?

Thanks a lot, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do it

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");
```

which will remove all the characters which are not either alphanumeric or special characters.

**EDIT :-**

As suggesed by [@npinti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243943/npinti)

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}0-9 ]", "");
```

Comment: Ideally `a-zA-Z` is replaced with `\p{L}`, since the latter deals with *letters* from all the languages, as opposed to the former which deals only with letters from the latin character set.

Comment: It worked but my project is in Swedish so it deleted all the special Swedish letters (å, ä and ö) is there a way to avoid that? 
I should have mentioned it in the question, I am going to edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all non-letter/digit characters and squish the spaces so you don't get multiple consecutive spaces:

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\d]+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all not letters and whitespaces.

```
text.replaceAll("[^\\sa-zA-Z]", "");
```

Legend:

- `^` - exclude given characters from being replaced
- `\\s` - all whitespaces (\n , \t , ' ')
- `a-zA-Z` - all letters

Example:

```
String in="12ASxA  sdr5%";
System.out.println(in.replaceAll("[^\\sa-zA-Z]", "")); // ASxA  sdr
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works. Do you know of a place where I can read more about how it works? Thanks again.

Comment: Generally google, but for starters: 
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html